# проблемы с настройкой БД в PYCharm Community (2020.1)

Tags: база-данных, jdbc, pycharm

столкнулся с сложностью подключения баз данных через DB Navigaitor в PyCharm Community (2020.1), не могу понять в чем дело.... может версия "комьюнити" не поддерживает данные функции? Заранее установленный плагин не хочет подключать БД ругается на какие-то драйвера (JDBC driver), которые установить внутри навигатора не удается,  инфу по по корректному пути к драйверу да и полезную инфу про сам драйвер "нарыть" не сумел. Причем SQLite Expert Pro данные таблиц (cстандартного файла sqlite.db)  из проекта Django отображает нормально. Подскажите плз куда копать!  Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, действительно версия «комьюнити», не поддерживает работу с БД внутри PyCharm, также не работает подсветка в статических файлах... решил проблему установкой pro версии. Лицензию бесплатную на 3 месяца, можно получить если решать задачи в курсах по программированию на stepik.